# How to Identify Hospital Re-Admissions?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am working with a cohort based on certain conditions and am trying to create an indicator to identify hospital re-admissions within 90 days.

I'm working with 5 tables of data, joining them together, and creating indicators for a cohort that meets three conditions. Within that cohort, the request asks for an indicator if the visit resulted in a subsequent readmission within 90 days  with '0' being longer than 90 days and '1' indicating a hospital readmission within 90 days or less, based on patient encounter data.

The encounters (e) dataset is set up like so:

```
PatientID |  EncounterID   |    Encounter START    |   Encounter    STOP  |
+---------+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      12 | 2      | 6/17/2013 6:51  | 6/17/2013 6:51
```

I tried creating a CASE WHEN statement with hospital start and stop dates and tried to see if I could calculate the difference in time for start dates for encounters that are described as "initial" versus "follow-up" but neither of these seem possible.

Since the request asks for the indicators within the dataset, I presume this has to all be nestled into one code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id                      AS 'Patient_Id', 
                e.id                      AS 'Encounter_Id', 
                e.start                   AS 'Hospital_Encounter_Date', 
                ( e.start - p.birthdate ) AS 'Age_at_Visit',
                CASE 
                  WHEN (e.STOP) - (e.START) <= 90 THEN 1 
                  ELSE 'N/A' 
                END                       '90_Day_Hospital_Readmission' 
FROM   patients p 
       JOIN encounters e 
         ON p.id = e.patient 
       JOIN medications m 
         ON p.id = m.patient 
WHERE  e.reasondescription = 'Drug overdose' 
       AND e.start >= '1999-07-15' 
       AND ( e.start - p.birthdate ) >= 18 
       AND ( e.start - p.birthdate ) <= 35 
GROUP  BY p.id 
ORDER  BY e.id
```

I expect the output to be either '1' for patients who have had a hospital readmission within 90 days of the end of their last visit.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If your date columns use the format like the one that you posted in the image I'm surprised that you even get any results.

Comment: While it might seem clear to you, "*Create an indicator to identify hospital re-admissions within 90 days*" is actually extremely ambiguous which is why no one has been trying to answer your question, it is very unclear to us what you are asking for.  Please give us a small example dataset, and the output that you would like to produce from that dataset.  You don't need to include anything that isn't relevant to your question like drug columns, etc.

Comment: Apologies - I'm clearly very new at all this. I tried to add clarification: since this is all going to be part of one code I included additional indicators that are part of the set. Essentially, I think the calculation for hospital admission has to be based on the time difference between a patient's discharge from a first visit between the admission for their second visit.

Comment: You are joining *three* tables. You must include relevant example data for all of them. And as mentioned by forpas, your date format is likely to be wrong.